# Is there an operator whose non-zero commutants are always injective?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space.

> Is there an operator $T \in B(H)$ such that, if
>   $TA=AT$ with $0 \ne A \in B(H)$, then $A$ injective ?

**Bonus question** : what is the set of all such operators ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In finite dimension, the invariant subspaces of $T$ are exactly the nullspaces of the operators that commute with $T$. So there is no such example in finite dimension $\geq 2$.

If $T$ is normal, it admits a handful of non-injective commuting projections (=reducing subspaces).

So this is a question about non-normal operators in infinite dimension.

As often when looking for a counterexample to a finite dimension property, the answer is the shift. Not the bilateral one, which is unitary whence normal. But the **unilateral shift**
$$
S:(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\longmapsto (0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\qquad x\in \ell^2.
$$
For every nonzero $A\in B(\ell^2)$ commuting with $S$, $A$ is injective.

**Proof:** the unilateral shift is conveniently realized as (unitarily equivalent to) the multiplication operator by $z$ on the [Hardy space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space) $H^2(\mathbb{D})$. In this context, it is well-known that the commutant of $S$ is exactly the algebra of analytic Toeplitz operators on $H^2$, i.e. multiplication operators by a bounded analytic function $\phi\in H^\infty$. Such nonzero multiplication operators are injective, since a nonzero analytic function on a domain has isolated zeros. QED.

**Reference:** "The commutant of analytic Toeplitz operators", Trans. AMS 1973, by [Deddens and Wong](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-184-00/S0002-9947-1973-0324467-0/).

Comment: Thank you @julien, I would indeed very interested in a reference.

Comment: Could the downvoter indicate if I said something wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. Have you find a reference ?

Comment: First I'm not comfortable with the operation $f(A)$ for a nonnormal operator $A$. But anyway, maybe here it's obvious that $f(S) = M_{f}$, isn't it ? So $M_{f}$ is non-zero and non-injective iff  $0<\mu(ker(f))<1$. Maybe it's obvious, but it's not clear for me why it's not allowed in $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$  ?

Comment: Ok there is a theorem saying that the zeros of an holomorphic function $f$ are isolated, so that $\mu(ker(f)) = 0$.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Well, if $p$ is a polynomial, you have no problem computing $p(A)$ if $A$ is not normal. One way to extend that is the [holomorphic functional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus).

Comment: A tiny nitpick about the finite dimensional case: the statement is true in dimension 1.  And dimension 0, for that matter.

Comment: @NateEldredge Right, I'll add that, thanks.